# Suite execution result in TestNG showing annotation methods and hence the test case count is mismatching - Firefox 68.0.1

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckoboard

Prerequisite:
Firefox 68.0.1
gecko driver version 0.21.0 (32 & 64 bits)
selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3
testng-6.11

I have a total of 300 test cases. When I execute the test suite using '.xml'
the execution count is mismatching.

It is considering/counting all the annotation methods as well (i.e @BeforeMethod & @AfterMethod) and add the sum to the total test cases execution.

I tried different versions of the gecko driver (0.21.0 to 0.24.0)

Expected result: total test case count (i.e 300)
Actual result: More than test cases count (506)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xgCJ.png)

Comment: Do you have any data driven tests? From what I remember, each item in the data set being fed into a single script is counted as another script. For example, if you have one data driven test that has 10 rows of data... it would be counted as 10 and not 1.

Comment: From the screenshots, it looks like you have `@DataProvider` dependent `@Test` methods. They would get counted as tests as well (as clarified by @JeffC)